# "Не удалось открыть веб-страницу" WebView

Tags: java, android, webview, кэширование

Здравствуйте, такая проблема:
Если отсутствует соединение с интернетом - пытаюсь брать страницу из кэша. (код ниже).

```
if ( !NetworkUtils.isDeviceOnline(this) ) { // loading offline
        settings.setCacheMode( WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ONLY );
    }
```

Но если и в кэше страницы пока нет, то [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Как отловить создание этой страницы и изменить её на нужную мне?** (onReceivedError не срабатывает)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сейчас есть 2 метода onReceivedError. Не вдавался в подробности какой зачем, но почему-то подхватывает ошибку именно тот, который не поддерживается уже. Не поддерживается, но работает и отлавливает нужные мне события для подмены html страницы.

P.S. лишний раз хочу напомнить (себе в частности), что вместо **view.loadData()** лучше использовать **view.loadDataWithBaseUR**L. Иначе возникают проблемы с кодировкой.